# Identificar si la Fecha u Hora ha cambiado al siguiente dia

Tags: php

necesito realizar una comprobación de Fecha u Hora.
La idea principal es que el código sea capaz de identificar si las 00:00 han ocurrido o no.
Y que además solo haga dicha revisión una vez al dia, es decir, a las 00:00
Hasta ahora solo eh intentado con métodos simples que no conducen a nada dado que realizarían la funcion siempre de todos modos al cumplir las condiciones o nunca si es que lo comparo con `==`.
Como el siguiente:

```
if(date("H") > 0){
    //Do Stuff...
}
```

Lo otro que he pensado, es identificar entre ciertas horas, pero recaigo en el mismo problema, si las condiciones se cumplen, el código se ejecutara indefinidamente dentro de esas horas.
No se si pueda realizarse de otro modo, o en otro lenguaje, como javascript.

Comment: ¿No sale mejor poner un cron job (o tarea programada) que ejecute el script a las 00.00 los días definidos?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias !!! es una buena idea, en este caso no importará si el pc está apagado o no cierto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la sugerencia de @aeportugal es lo más adecuado, porque con tareas programadas siempre se ejecutará a la misma hora y no dependes de que alguien ingrese al sitio para realizar la verificación.

Además, si los proceso que vas a realizar son muy pesados, podrías retardar la carga de la página para el usuario que "tuvo la fortuna" de ingresar cuando toca actualizar.

Sin tareas programadas, lo que necesitas hacer es guardar la fecha de la última vez que se ejecutó el código y, si es un día diferente, ejecutarlo nuevamente y actualizar el dato. Lo ideal es que lo almacenes en base de datos, pero también puedes hacerlo con un archivo de texto.

```
<?php
// Tomar la fecha, día actual
$hoy = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
// Leer archivo con la fecha de última ejecución
$ultima = (file_exists(''fecha.txt')) ? file_get_contents(''fecha.txt') : 0;

// Si la fecha guardada es menor que la actual (cero horas de hoy)
if($ultima < $hoy) {
    /* ******* Aquí ejecutas el código ******* */
    // Al terminar, actualizas la fecha
    file_put_contents('fecha.txt', $hoy);
}
```

Insisto, es mejor hacerlo con base de datos, porque trabajar con archivos no es muy confiable, toma esta respuesta solo como una idea para adaptar.

Comment: Este es uno de los métodos que se me ocurrió durante el fin de semana, lo intentaré así pero además considerando lo que @aeportugal mencionó